# Does NHAML require ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: nhaml

Couldn't find this directly on the NHAML project page, so i was wondering if you need to run the ASP.NET MVC in order to use NHaml or if I can use this on a "normal" ASP.NET webpage?

Also, i've read that you'd need to intercept requests for Sass and manually call the builder for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not require ASP.NET MVC although there's an implementation for it. You could process NHaml templates even in a console application if you will.

Comment: I've got MVC 2 running now, but when following the guides to install NHaml, I can't seem to find the ControllerBuilder for Nhaml anywhere, so i'm currently figuring out on how to get Nhaml enabled on  ASp.NET MVC 2

Answer (score 1):

Question somewhat duplicated with the answer here: [Can NHaml be used as a general purpose template engine? (outside of MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384022/can-nhaml-be-used-as-a-general-purpose-template-engine-outside-of-mvc)

Quote:

> Yes, it can be used without ASP.Net
>   MVC. I use it for my own web server
>   (but that doesn't mean that you HAVE
>   to use it with web servers).
>
> Check out how I use it here:
>   http://webserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/50874#671672
>
> What you do in short is something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> TemplateEngine _templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
>
> // Add a type used in the template. Needed to that nhaml can
> ```
>
> find it when compiling the template
>       _templateEngine.Options.AddReferences(typeof
>   (TypeInYourAssembly));
>
> ```
> // base class for all templates
> _templateEngine.Options.TemplateBaseType
> ```
>
> = typeof (BaseClassForTemplates);
>
> ```
> //class providing content to the engine, should implement
> ```
>
> ITemplateContentProvider
>       _templateEngine.Options.TemplateContentProvider
>   = this;
>
> ```
> // compile the template, 
> CompiledTemplate template = _templateEngine.Compile(new List<string> {layoutName, viewPath},
>                                                                 typeof (TemplateImplementation));
>
> //create a instance
> var instance = (NHamlView)template.CreateInstance();
>
> // provide the view data used by the template
> instance.ViewData = viewData;
>
> // render it into a text writer
> instance.Render(writer);
> ```